# Getting osm2pgrouting working

Tags: postgis, pgrouting, osm2pgrouting

Using PostgreSQL 9.6 and osm2pgrouting 2.2 I am not able to let osm2pgrouting work.
Starting from the command line, I get always some mistakes. I think I tried everything, and am getting a bit frustrated. Can anybody help?

Path of osm2pgrouting: C:\Program Files\Postgresql\9.6\bin\
Path of the OSM file: C:\nederland_osm
 Name of the OSM file: netherlands-latest.osm

What would be he right command? 
For instance I have tried:

osm2pgrouting -f C:\nederland_osm\netherlands-latest.osm -d pgr --port=5432 --schema=ospr -c C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\9.6\bin\mapconfig_for_cars.xml

Comment: First of all use "C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\9.6\bin\mapconfig_for_cars.xml"

Comment: What error do you get?

Comment: Well, found out what the problem was; It didn't hande the space between Program Files ... So put it between double quotes: osm2pgrouting -f  "C:\nederland_osm\netherlands-latest.osm" -d Maas -c "C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\9.6\bin\mapconfig_for_cars.xml"       That is part of the solution, the script runs now, but I guess memory is an issue now... Will solve that also......

Comment: Do you run this on Windows with Ubuntu bash?

Answer (score 1):

On Windows; Navigate to your bin file under PostgreSQL directory  from CMD and write;

```
osm2pgrouting.exe --f C:\Users\user\Desktop\qgis\export.osm --conf C:\Users\user\Desktop\qgis\mapconfig.xml --dbname yourdb --username postgres --password 111
```